# Python code not writing into file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have several text files in a folder, containing a list of names and adjectives. I have managed to create a script that takes random names, second names and such and creates a character from that data.

What I am using for that is the following code, which takes all the lines from the text file and places them in an array (This approach has worked well so far):

```
file=open("file_name","r")
array_name = []
for line in file:
    array_name.append( line.rstrip('\n') )

(Repeat this for every text file)
```

The sources I take that data from are often badly formatted (Everything in caps, nothing capitalised, etc), so I am trying to create another piece of code that capitalises every single word in all those text files. After extensive searching I've found that title() does exactly what I want to do, and I am trying to implement that approach using part of the previous code.

I am running into some trouble, especially because apparently I have created a piece of code that does what I want but does not actually write the changes to the file. Here is what I have done:

```
file=open("file_name","r+")
for line in file:
    line=line.title()
file.close
```

The idea is to open the file in read and write mode, read a line, change that line to the same line with title() applied and repeat until the end of the file.

Am I forgetting to add something? I have been trying things and thinking about it for some time now and I am not able to make this work. I am assuming the problem is in the line=line.title() line, but all my attempts have ended with the text files being empty or screwed up in some other way.

Comment: Why not use `file.readlines()` or `list(file)`? (Note that these don't strip newlines.) Also, it's good practice to open files in a `with` statement: `with open('file_name', 'r') as f:`.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for the same reason `for item in list: item = x` doesn't work. You only modify the local variable `line`, not the actual file. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with files to recommend the best way to perform the modification. One way would be to write the modified version to a temporary file and then move the temporary file over the original, but I have no idea whether that's good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use a context manager, the `with` statement:

```
with open('file_name', 'r+') as my_file: # this automatically closes it
    lines = my_file.readlines()
    # now, rewrite the data
    for line in lines:
        my_file.write(line.title())
```

Edit: to completely rewrite the data, you have to use a `'w+'` buffer mode (so first you can read it, than write over the original data) and also set the file pointer back to the beginning of the file:

```
with open('file_name', 'w+') as my_file:
    lines = my_file.readlines()
    # set the file pointer at the beginning of the file
    my_file.seek(0, 0)
    # now, rewrite the data
    for line in lines:
        my_file.write(line.title())
```

The previous issue (with my first example) is that once you have fully read the file, **the file pointer is at the end of the file.** Thus, you have to set it back to the beginning using the `file.seek` method.

Comment: Do you need to reposition the file between reading and writing it?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the with statement. I have tried this approach and it works, but only the second half of the file has been modified and I don't know which statement causes this to happen. Edit: I see, this takes a line, applies title() and then appends it to the end of the file without deleting the original line.

Comment: @Achifaifa Check my latest edit, I think that should solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    words = {}
    for whichfile in ['firstname', 'lastname', 'noun', 'adjective']:
        # read all words from file
        with open(whichfile + '.txt') as inf:
            words[whichfile] = [line.strip().title() for line in inf]

        # write capitalized words back to file
        with open(whichfile + '.txt', 'w') as outf:
            outf.write('\n'.join(words[whichfile]))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```